# all arrangement of elements of string python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python.

I have got a string separted by comma. 
Like 'a,b,c,d'

I need to separate get the elements separated and then need to find all the possible arrangements for the comma separated elements.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to learn, think how you can do this by recursion !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use permutation of itertools module

```
>>> a = 'aaa,bbb,ccc'
>>> b = a.split(',')
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.permutations(b))
>>> [('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb'), ('bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc'), ('bbb', 'c
cc', 'aaa'), ('ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa')]
```

Comment: ``b`` is not defined in your solution !

Comment: got removed...added again

Comment: It seems weird to me to use ``[i for i in ...]`` instead of ``list(...)``.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: I added quickly. Thanks for the tip. Editted.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for elem in itertools.permutations(testStr.split(',')):
        print ",".join(elem)


a,b,c,d
a,b,d,c
a,c,b,d
a,c,d,b
a,d,b,c
a,d,c,b
b,a,c,d
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is best

Here's the traditional Recursion technique

```
def permu(s, e=''):
    if len(s) == 0: print ",".join([ i for i in e])
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            permu(s[0:i] + s[i+1:], e+s[i])

str="a,b,c,d"
permu("".join(str.split(',')))
```